# Angular 9 ngcc try to scan entire disk

Tags: angular, npm-install, angular-ivy

I migrated my Angular 8 to Angular 9 following angular.io guide, but i encounter an issue while generating ivy entry points.

When i do `npm install`, i see the following error during `ngcc` command execution.

```
ngcc

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'E:/System Volume Information'
    at Object.lstatSync (fs.js:917:3)
```

I'm using Windows 10 and Node 12, but i tried on macOS and i get the same result (of course on another system protected path).

Following my postinstall script

`"postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"`

I searched for this issue and proposed solutions tell to change folders permissions, but i don't want to unsecure my OS.

Also i can't do ng serve without having ngcc working.

How to prevent ngcc to scan the entire disk and only do what it should do ? Is there any known bug about this ?

EDIT :

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@root/*": ["/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `tsconfig.json `, `tsconfig.app.json` and `angular.json` files? There might a problem with settings path somethere

Comment: Thanks a lot, the issue was in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in tsconfig.js

```
{
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@root/*": ["/*"]
    }
    ...
}
```

I expected the @root path only target the root of the project, but i forget the dot to make it relative

`"@root/*": ["./*"]`